# Why is this function being undone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table that contains a lot of data. Certain cells can be clicked on, and when they do, their contents are replaced with an editing interface, which includes among other things a cancel button.

When the cancel button is clicked, the following Javascript (with a bit of jQuery) is run:

```
function undo_changes(el) {

  // Restore the previously-stored original innerHTML and event handler
  el.innerHTML = cell_contents;
  cell_contents = undefined;
  $(el).bind('click', box_click);

  // Restore the form's action and events
  $(main_form).attr('action',main_form_destination).attr('onchange', 'return true');
}
```

The cancel button is implemented as follows (`this.parentNode` refers to the cell):

```
<button onclick="undo_changes(this.parentNode)">Cancel</button>
```

When I click the cancel button, nothing appears to change. When I step through the code in the debugger, the changes happen as expected. However, upon reaching the end of the function, suddenly all the changes are reverted. What's going on?

I'm running Chromium under Ubuntu and jQuery 1.10.2.

### Further details

The debugger shows the following below my function on the call stack. I don't pretend to understand it.

```
(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {undo_changes(this.parentNode)
};}}}})
```

For some reason, upon leaving my function, execution jumps to jQuery at line 4761. Following that, jQuery somehow calls my function `box_click()` which creates what I'm trying to delete.

### By request

As I type this edit, the problem has been solved. Nevertheless, I was asked to show `box_click()`, which creates the editing interface. Here's the version that was current when I originally posted the question:

```
function box_click() {
  if(cell_contents) {
    alert('Please deal with the other place you\'re editing first.');
    return false;
  }
  var id = this.id;
  var student_id = $(this).attr('student_id');
  var class_date = $(this).attr('date');
  var html = make_radio('attendance','None',get_current(this) == 'None');
  html += make_radio('attendance','Present',get_current(this) == 'Present');
  html += make_radio('attendance','Absent',get_current(this) == 'Absent');
  html += make_radio('attendance','Tardy',get_current(this) == 'Tardy');
  html += '<input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="'+student_id+'">';
  html += '<input type="hidden" name="class_date" value="'+class_date+'">';
  html += '<button onclick="undo_changes(this.parentNode)">Cancel</button>';
  cell_contents = this.innerHTML;
  var f = $(main_form);
  main_form_destination = f.attr('action');
  f.attr('action', '/classes/ajax_update_attendance/'+id+'/<?=$class_id?>').attr('onchange', 'submit(this)'); // There's a smattering of PHP on this line
  this.innerHTML = html;
  $(this).unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: The button could be refreshing the page. Try changing your handler to `onclick="undo_changes(this.parentNode); return false;"`

Comment: Good thought, but it didn't work. The problem is unchanged.

Comment: I believe that's because your click event is bubbling up. And you can't prevent that with an inline handler, use jquery to bind the button click.

Comment: @bfavaretto: Bingo. You solved it. If you turn it into an answer, I'l upvote and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comment by [bfavaretto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825789/bfavaretto) solved my problem:

> I believe that's because your click event is bubbling up. And you can't prevent that with an inline handler, use jquery to bind the button click.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're running into a situation where additional click events are being bound to the element every time your `undo_changes` function runs.  What if you try this:

```
 $(el).unbind('click').bind('click', box_click);
```

This will assure that only the current click handler will be bound to the click event for that  element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was already unbinding the click event when the edit interface was created. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion, but it had no effect--presumably because the event was already unbound.