# Obscure nested "with" statements

Tags: javascript

I'm reviewing an outsourced project for a friend and there is a really odd Javascript code block right at the top of each page.  **Clearly it doesn't do anything** but it's so *trippy* I can't help but wonder how the capital F' it came to be:

```js
(function() {
    with (this[2]) {
        with (this[1]) {
            with (this[0]) {
               return function(event) {};
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Unless I'm missing something a developer would have to be influenced by some kind of amphetamine in order to produce this on their own so I'm assuming it's the remains of an automated tool but can't for the life of me imagine a useful scenario.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  Has anyone encountered anything similar?

---

This is absolutely positively ***everything*** with exception to the opening `<script>` tag from byte zero in the document.  As already stated I'm aware that it doesn't do anything - even if the expression *was* executed `this` would be the `window` or `global` which wouldn't have any numeric indices so it fails dismally at the first line.

I'm aware that `with` as a concept leaves much to be desired and as a practical joke it's not funny.  I'll leave the question open - maybe some monkey in a closet somewhere knows something about it.

Comment: Remnants of a minifier?

Comment: Is this the entire code or is there more to it?

Comment: Use of the with statement is not recommended

Comment: @RocketHazmat right at the top - before any doctype etc.

Comment: Are you *sure* there isn't any more to this?  Because `(function(){})` does absolutely nothing.  As shown, this function never actually runs.

Comment: @j08691 I'm not ruling it out none of the code is actually minified...

Comment: That code doesn't even execute the function. It's useless. More code doesn't matter.

Comment: @all I'm aware of that - that is literally everything inside the `script` tag - hence why I'm sure it's the remains of something been and gone - just curious as to what.

Comment: @Emissary: Maybe your friend put this here just to confuse you!  Like a prank ;)

Comment: @RocketHazmat crossed my mind :) but alas as code humour goes there are better examples.

Comment: @Emissary: Have you considered just asking your friend? Maybe he can hunt down what happened with the VCS.

Comment: @Bergi - sadly there is no version-control (don't even get me started on that :P).  It's a partially completed system built on Yii by a Ukrainian team that they are no longer in contact with.  I've not been actively searching for an answer to this specifically as it's only a curiosity but I have been skimming through the front-end code and will update if I find anything incriminating.  Oh ye, and my friend isn't a developer hence why I'm doing it.

Comment: It looks like it was pasted as a placeholder for handling some event that wasn't bubbling up properly? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803329/why-is-this-function-being-undone and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128723 which both mention that code, but with actual functions being called.  I'm guessing somebody pulled it from a framework lib and pasted it in with the intention of filling in the function later to handle something that wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

This might be of interest... it seems it's coming from a debugger. Which debugger I know not, nor why it would add such odd code:

[Why is this function being undone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803329/why-is-this-function-being-undone)

Perhaps you could ask Scott Severance?

All that being said, I'd personally prefer the term ape-like descendant...

> **Please Note:** This question was definitely rather random, but I especially like the fact that the (at least partial) answer was found already existing on StackOverflow...?! Is there anything that SO doesn't have an answer for, it's getting like one of those people who never likes to admit they don't know something!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to [MDN][1] the with statement is used to include an object into the statements within.</strike> 

I just stumbled across a similar piece of code in Chrome.
I made a mistake of using the "in" keyword as a var/object and it replaced my code it the nested "withs", it replaced the code only in the dev tools sources file.
So it is from a debugger, the with statements were probably used in its code to organize the hierarchy of the JS, it came across the "in" and found nothing to find something in.
I gave up on the file (I was testing SSE and... failed) so I am now trying to recreate the error.